# Why is this prolog program not compiling?

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog, prolog-dif

I have a prolog program. These lines are preventing it from compiling:

```
wins(A,B,C,D) :- convert(A,W), value(W,P), convert(B,X), value(X,Q), 
convert(C, Y), value(Y,R), convert(D,Z), value(Z,S), card(A), card(B), card(C), card(D),
(P+Q)>(R+S), (P+Q)<22, A/=B, A/=C, A/=D, B/=C, B/=D, C/=D. %this is not compiling

wins(A,B,C,D) :- convert(A,W), value(W,P), convert(B,X), value(X,Q), 
convert(C,Y), value(Y,R), convert(D,Z), value(Z,S), card(A), card(B), card(C), card(D),
(R+S)>21, (P+Q)<22, A/=B, A/=C, A/=D, B/=C, B/=D, C/=D. %this is not compiling
```

I get the following errors:

```
| ?- [blackjack].
compiling /home/ross/flash/current/CS390/blackjack.pl for byte code...
/home/ross/flash/current/CS390/blackjack.pl:47:25: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
/home/ross/flash/current/CS390/blackjack.pl:51:22: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
2 error(s)
compilation failed
```

Comment: It would be better that you keep the question there, Joseph, even if it is solved, so that others who come afterwards with the same problem can see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/=` is not a valid operator. You must have meant `\=`.

(Better yet, use `dif(A,B)` if your Prolog supports it, and put the `dif` calls before the rest of the clause.)